# Regex match only exact words

Tags: javascript, regex

I use the following function to give certain words spans with classnames:

```
$.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts, color) {

  var tag = opts.tag || 'span'
    , words = opts.words || []
    , regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi') // case insensitive
    , replacement = '<'+ tag + ' class="' + color +'">$&</'+ tag +'>';

  return this.html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace(regex, replacement);
});
};
```

The problem is it matches **redundant** in *this* for example. How can I make it match only the exact words (red but not redundant)? I did some research and found i need to do something like this:

```
(\w+)
```

But I dont know where to add it next to **gi**

The Function i would run to add 
     
to a word is:

```
<p>Only one redundant word is red</p>

$('p').wrapInTag({
      tag: 'span',
      words: ['red']
}, 'blue');
```

Thanks

Comment: Created a quick JSFiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/611g00n6/] from the code you provided, seems like red is getting matched as expected, but so is the 'red' in 'redundant'. Is that what your problem is?

Comment: @Chirag64 Yes, thats the problem :)

Answer (score 11):

I don't think it has anything to do with `(\w+)`. If I'm reading the problem correctly you want to match a word, not substring of a word. This can be achieved using word boundaries `\b`

Like so `\b(is|red|blue)\b` will match exactly `is` or `red` or `blue`.

[MDN on word boundary regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary)

Comment: What about `/(\w+)/gi` isn't that OK?

Comment: @mortezaT I don't understand, how does that prevent you from matching substring of a word?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/611g00n6/1/

Comment: @anubhava for multiple words in the words array it only worked when i did `RegExp('(\\b)(' + words.join('|') + ')(\\b)', 'gi')` are the brackets between the words that important

Comment: Yes brackets are important for grouping words together